# changing selected values in INSERT statement

Tags: sql

I am trying to write an SQL script to migrate some data. Imagine this situation:

Table to migrate:

```
OLDTABLE
---------------
ID    VALUE     OLDVALUE
1     A         A
2     B         B
```

Expected target state

```
NEWTABLE
---------------
ID    VALUE     NEWVALUE
1     A         Y
2     B         Z
```

What I have so far is:

```
INSERT INTO NEWTABLE (ID, VALUE, NEWVALUE)
SELECT
    ID,
    VALUE,
    OLDVALUE
FROM OLDTABLE;
```

My question is how can I modify the value selected from `OLDTABLE.OLDVALUE` before inserting it into `NEWTABLE.NEWVALUE` so that it is Y for every A and Z for every B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good old [`CASE` expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx):

```
INSERT INTO NEWTABLE (ID, VALUE, NEWVALUE)
SELECT
    ID,
    VALUE,
    CASE OLDVALUE
       WHEN 'A' THEN 'Y'
       WHEN 'B' THEN 'Z'
       ELSE OLDVALUE
    END
FROM OLDTABLE;
```

(I've assumed that if it's not `A` or `B`, it should be left unaltered)

Comment: Thanks! Will accept this answer as soon as I can (time limit) as you were a little faster than okrumnow.

Comment: @André - our answers are subtly different. I'm using a Simple Case expression, okrumnow is using a Searched Case expression. You can read about them and the differences between them via the link I've provided.

Comment: But they don't differ in the resulting data, do they?

Comment: @okrumnow - no, I was just trying to help Andre decide which answer he wanted to use - I might be arguing *against* them accepting my answer here.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. As I only need equality checks I find the simple version better readable. But it's good to know the searched case too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO NEWTABLE (ID, VALUE, NEWVALUE)
SELECT ID, VALUE,
  CASE WHEN OLDVALUE = 'A' THEN 'Y'
       WHEN OLDVALUE = 'B' THEN 'Z'
       ELSE 'NOT FOUND' -- handle NOT FOUND case here
  END AS NEWVALUE
FROM OLDTABLE
```